# Unknown error on Excel VBA Shell() function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel VBA function to open a log file for viewing and it does everything correctly, except that it always throws an error after I close the file from viewing:

```
Private Sub ViewLog_Click()
  On Error GoTo LogFileOpenHandler:
    If Shell("notepad.exe " & LOG_FULL_FILENAME, vbMaximizedFocus) <> 0 Then
      ' Log file opened successfully
      MsgBox "log file opened"
    Else
      MsgBox "Oopsies! Could not open log file for viewing."
    End If

LogFileOpenHandler:
  MsgBox "Oops...Unknown error occured. Could not open log file for viewing."
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

However, if I insert a `Exit Sub` as the last statement in `If Shell(...) <> 0 Then` there are no errors caught.

Could someone please explain to me what the error is and why it's thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it says there is an error is because you don't have the `Exit Sub` (like you alluded to) after the `If` block. So each time the program is run it runs all the way through and produces the message box under `LogFileOpenHandler:` because there is nothing to stop the code from executing that script.

If you add the `Exit Sub` back in, it will run as you want it to:

```
Private Sub ViewLog_Click()
  On Error GoTo LogFileOpenHandler:
    If Shell("notepad.exe " & LOG_FULL_FILENAME, vbMaximizedFocus) <> 0 Then
      ' Log file opened successfully
      MsgBox "log file opened"
    Else
      MsgBox "Oopsies! Could not open log file for viewing."
    End If

    Exit Sub 

LogFileOpenHandler:
  MsgBox "Oops...Unknown error occured. Could not open log file for viewing."
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh you are right, I completely misunderstood flags. Now I understand.